# Jquery animate top left dynamic

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using a jquery animate with the html5 drag and drop and I wanted to make the same animation that google drive do.

I manage to do that :

```
element.bind('drag', function(e) {
      _.each(draggedFiles, function(id) { //draggedFiles is an array of id
        id = 'fs-row-' + id;
        var newRow = angular.element('body').find('div#'+ id); // Element being animated

        newRow.animate({
          width: 190,
          height: 50,
          top: e.originalEvent.pageY,
          left: e.originalEvent.pageX,
        }, 'medium', function() {
           // When the animation is over the tag element are being removed from the DOM
          _.each(draggedFiles, function(id) {
            id = 'fs-row-' + id;
            angular.element('body').find('div#'+ id).remove();
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

The animation is working fine and go to the mouse position. But if I move the mouse during the animation, the animate will not update the top and left on the fly but instead just continue to move to where I clicked instead of following the mouse.

The drag event allow my to know the position of the mouse in the window. Is it possible to trigger the animate again until it reach the mouse position ?

[edit] I am looking at the jQuery doc and found that I can use progress or step, but I can't find if its possible to update the top and left from those two event. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer looking up the jQuery doc using the step function, maybe it will help someone in the future. Mainly you can edit on each step the end or start of each property animated. I just had to update the end with the position of my mouse.

```
    var y = 0;
    var x = 0;
    element.bind('drag', function(e) {
      _.each(draggedFiles, function(id) {
        id = 'fs-row-' + id;
        var newRow = angular.element('body').find('div#'+ id);

        newRow.animate({
          opacity: 1,
          width: 190,
          height: 50,
          top: e.originalEvent.pageY,
          left: e.originalEvent.pageX
        }, {
          duration: 400,
          step: function( now, tween ) {
            if (tween.prop === 'top') {
              tween.end = y;
            }
            if (tween.prop === 'left') {
              tween.end = x;
            }
          },
          complete: function() {
            newRow.remove();
            angular.element(dragElement).animate({
              width: 190,
              height: 50,
              opacity: 1
            }, 'fast');
          }
        });
      });

      y = e.originalEvent.pageY + 1;
      x = e.originalEvent.pageX;
    });
```